# MongoDB Configuration and Installation

Tags: mongodb, database

How to Configure MongoDB, can any one define step for installation and configuration? I was tried to install but i couldn't get success. So if any one have any information than please inform me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try below link it must be useful:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/

Answer (score 2):

This [document here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) can help you to install mongodb.

Comment: thank you for documentation. Is there any GUI-tool available like my sql for oracle sql?

Comment: You can use "mongohub" on your desktop,or "RockMongo" in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

For beginners, Mongodb provides documentation. Explore it, you will get the idea easily.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before doing so. In this case you should at least provide a link to the documentation you are referring to as you can see in the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of configuring MongoDB in a Spring based application.

```
@Configuration
public class Config(){
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws UnknownHostException{
return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(protocol://username:password@servername/databasename)),"Database_name_here"); //mongodb is the protocol
}    

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException{
return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
}
}
```

When you want to bootstrap this configuration in a main class, you will do that by using Spring's `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
MongoOperations template = context.getBean(MongoTemplate.class);
```

Then, you will call all the MongoTemplate's methods on MongoOperations's instance.